# Material Question

Tags: captain-america, wolverine, marvel, adamantium, vibranium

I have a question about different types of materials shown in comic books. Which is material is stronger? Captain America's `vibranium` shield or Wolverine's `adamantium` bones? Specifically, could Wolverine punch a hole through Captain's Shield?

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Proto-Adamantium) explains a lot about the various virtually indestructible materials and their origin. I would recommend reading it. However, it also makes it very clear that Captain America's shield would win out against any blows from Wolverine's skeleton.

> Proto-Adamantium is the official name for the metal that makes up Captain America's Shield. It has never been recreated and is the absolute most invulnerable item in all of existence.